# How publish from sbt to differenet maven repository?

Tags: maven, repository, sbt, local, publish

Sbt has comand `publishM2` which publish project to default maven repository - `~.m2/repository`. What if I have repository in different place? How tell sbt to publish in different place (`D:\repository` for exmaple)?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html

You can use `publish` command and you need to specify `publishTo :=  ...`. Check to link to see some examples.

Comment: It seems that I need to modify some configuration files. Can I publish to different folder just specify parameters in command line?